# Public IP address of the network router where Alexa is connected

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

How can I send the public IP address where Alexa is via a url. I have to make an http GET request where I put as a parameter the public IP address of the Alexa network (IP Router).

Answer (score 1):

You can not access that information from the skill. If you could, that would be a huge security issue.